# How to pass formulas or quosures in dplyr verbs R as arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, nse, lazyeval

I am not able to use formulas or quosures in filter expressions in dplyr.

```
a_table <- data_frame(key = rep(letters[1:2], each = 2), 
  value = replace(runif(4), mod(1:4, 2) == 1, NA))

a_cond <- quo(not(is.na(value)))

filter(a_table, !!a_cond)
```

Yields the error

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : invalid argument type
```

I have read the vignettes on NSE and dplyr programming, and tried different calls to this:

```
a_cond <- interp(~not(is.na(value_)), value_ = as.name("value"))
```

But haven't really nailed it.
Thank you for your help.

The Session Info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 17.10

other attached packages:
 [1] rlang_0.1.1       readxl_1.0.0      aws.s3_0.3.3      magrittr_1.5     
 [5] dplyr_0.5.0       ggplot2_2.2.1     tidyr_0.6.1       dtplyr_0.0.2     
 [9] lazyeval_0.2.0    purrr_0.2.2.2     data.table_1.10.4 feather_0.3.1    
[13] readr_1.1.0       lubridate_1.6.0   stringr_1.2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the quosures issue, I had to update with `install_github` instead of `update.packages`.

This didn't solve the issue with formulas based on `lazyeval::interp()`, though.

For this to work, I figured out how to make the equivalent with quosures as well.  Instead of

```
interp(~!is.na(value_), value_ = as.name("value"))
```

I did

```
quo(!is.na( !!sym("value") ))
```

And now all works as it should.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

We can use it an `expr`

```
a_cond <- rlang::expr(magrittr::not(is.na(value)))
filter(a_table, !!a_cond)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  key   value
#   <chr> <dbl>
#1 a     0.225
#2 b     0.519
```

Or as `quosure`, but make sure the function `not` is from `magrittr`

```
a_cond <- quo(magrittr::not(is.na(value)))
filter(a_table, !!a_cond)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   key   value
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a     0.225
#2 b     0.519
```

Comment: Strange.  With `expr` I'm still getting an error with `object 'value' not found`.  With quosure, it also says `invalid argument type`.  I'm adding my relevant `sessionInfo()` as an edit.

Comment: @Diego What is your dplyr version?  I am using `dplyr_0.7.4`

Comment: Mmph... that would be `dplyr_0.5.0`.  @akrun.   I'll do the update.

Comment: @Diego That would be old version which wouldn't be compatible with the quosures

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  Updating `dplyr` solved the quosure problem.  For anyone reading this (note to self), remember to do the update with `install_github`, not `update.packages`.

Comment: Asking one last thing @akrun since it still doesn't work with `lazyeval` `interp` formulas.  Are they in the scope of new quosures?

Comment: @Diego  I am not sure about.  May be the `interp` and all those stufl will be deprecated

Comment: That makes sense.  `quo` and `!!` did it for me this time.  There's no need of `interp` anymore.

Comment: Right.  Marking the answer.  While @akrun 's suggestions helped me get to the point of my package being outdated, the solution was mainly to just update it, so I typed that up for an answer.  Cheers.